# Difference b/w had to and would have to

Tags: would

“ Dinner at Billy's was more a punishment than a reward, since anyone who sat at the dinner table would have to listen to Billy's father's interminable harangues against the government.”

Could someone please clarify why the author has used “would have to” instead of “had to” in the above sentence? I’m not acquainted with this usage of would; what is it?

Comment: _Would_ implying habitual behaviour - "In the evenings we would often sit up late talking".

Comment: @KateBunting yes, but in this sentence, it seems that the author talks about only one occasion, so how could it be a habitual would? Could you please clarify further?

Comment: As you didn't provide the context for the sentence, I assumed that the author was describing 'dinner at Billy's' as a recurring event.

Comment: In sentences, "I thought I had to take a ticket",  "I thought I would have to take a ticket" the difference is clear. The first is a past obligation (not relevant now), but the second is still futuristic.  It is just that the introducing verb 'thought' being in past tense, 'will have to' was changed to 'would have to'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this looks like a conditional sentence:

> *If* anyone **sat** at the dinner table they **would have to** listen to Billy's father's interminable harangues against the government.”

So I presume the author is not only referring to this particular occasion, especially because of the use of *anyone*. Whosoever sits at that table will have to listen to him. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, the 278th Conditional, perhaps (ie unless [tchrist](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65796/difference-between-if-present-will-infinitive-and-if-present-would/66143#66143) nailed it).. And 'had to' is as valid an option as 'would have to' in either the 'anyone who ...' or 'if anyone ...' variants, with the 'would have to' emphasising the hypotheticality to a greater degree.